# Django Select from a Subquery

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to query with window function and then do some group by aggregation on the subquery. But I couldn't make it with ORM method. It will return `aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls`

Is there any way to make a query like SQL below without using `.raw()`

```
SELECT a.col_id, AVG(a.max_count) FROM (
  SELECT col_id,
  MAX(count) OVER (PARTITION BY part_id ORDER BY part_id) AS max_count
  FROM table_one
) a
GROUP BY a.col_id;
```

Example

table_one

```
| id | col_id | part_id | count |
| -- | ------ | ------- | ----- |
| 1  | c1     | p1      | 3     |
| 2  | c2     | p1      | 2     |
| 3  | c3     | p2      | 1     |
| 4  | c2     | p2      | 4     |
```

First I want to get the max base on the part_id

```
| id | col_id | part_id | count | max_count |
| -- | ------ | ------- | ----- | --------- |
| 1  | c1     | p1      | 3     | 3         |
| 2  | c2     | p1      | 2     | 3         |
| 3  | c3     | p2      | 1     | 4         |
| 4  | c2     | p2      | 4     | 4         |
```

And finally get the avarage of max_count group by col_id

```
| col_id | avg(max_count) |
| ------ | -------------- |
| c1     | 3              |
| c2     | 3.5            |
| c3     | 4              |
```

The models I have now

```
def Part(models.Model):
    part_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharFields()

def Col(models.Model):
    part_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharFields()

def TableOne(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    col_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Col,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='table_one_col'
    )
    part_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Part,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='table_one_part'
    )
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to do group by after the partition by. This is the query I did which will bring error.

```
query = TableOne.objects.annotate(
    max_count=Window(
        expression=Max('count'),
        order_by=F('part_id').asc(),
        partition_by=F('part_id')
    )
).values(
    'col_id'
).annotate(
    avg=Avg('max_count')
)
```

Comment: Can you provide the Django model and queryset attempt if you have it?

Comment: I already attached the models and the query I made

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you provide examples? Are you getting the _max_ `count` for each `part_id` in `table_one` in the subquery? How does getting an average work from that?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the models, I've corrected it and provides the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in Django, you don't need to use window functions. First the subquery is a `Part` queryset that is annotated with the max count from `TableOne`

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Subquery, OuterRef

parts = Part.objects.filter(
    id=OuterRef('part_id')
).annotate(
    max=Max('table_one_part__count')
)
```

Then annotate a `TableOne` queryset with the max count from the subquery, perform `values` on the column we want to group by (`col_id` ) and then annotate again with the average to generate your desired output

```
TableOne.objects.annotate(
    max_count=Subquery(parts.values('max')[:1])
).values(
    'col_id'
).annotate(
    Avg('max_count')
)
```